# Clone several nodes

Tags: nodes, entities

I'm searching a module to clone several nodes automatically when i create a project node type. To explain better : When i create a new node of Project type for exemple, i need to clone some nodes and tie this nodes to my node project.

I have tried node_clone but we should use a button to clone the node. For the moment i developped a small code to clone my node like this :

```
$p1template=variable_get('myvar_p1');
$p1=node_load($p1template);
unset($p1->nid);
unset($p1->vid);
$p1->title='Processus P1'.$projectid;
$p1->field_px_projet['und'][0]['target_id']=$projectid;
node_save($p1);
```

But i had a second problem with the field_collection. when i cloned the nodes, the field_collection keep the same reference and when i modify a field collection, all the nodes cloned field_collection was modify...

How can i fix this problem ?

PS : Sorry for my english..

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node clone module has a hook for this, hook_clone_node_alter(&$node, $context). When you clone nodes programmatically, make sure you alter their state and values inside this function.

```
function module_name_clone_alter(&$node, $context){
    switch ($context['method']) {
        case 'prepopulate':
          // Change field values ....

          break;

        case 'save-edit':
          // Perform operations when saving the node.

          break;
      }
    }
```